# Get page load time, X times

Tags: javascript, php, performance, curl

I am doing a research about the speed of multiple Javascript charting libraries. I made some testpages, 4 graphs each with libraries such as Highcharts, Flot, D3, AmCharts, FusionCharts etc.

Now I want run each page 100 times to get their individual loading speed and average for each library. I am actually not even sure if this is even possible.

I thought about doing the following:

1. Load the page with the graphs with CURL (PHP)

   ```
   function getContents($url) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   $header = array(
       'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12',
       'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
       'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
       'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
       'Keep-Alive: 115',
       'Connection: keep-alive',
   );

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
   }
   ```
2. On the page itself, capture loading time with Javascript and write that to a file in PHP.

   ```
   var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "SaveTime.php",
       data: {action: "saveloadtime", time: loadTime}
   })
       .done(function(msg) {

   });
   ```

However, this will run only once and besides that I do not get any result in the file on my server.

- Is it possible that the Javascript does not get executed while calling the page trough PHP?
- How do I loop 100 times trough a page: wait until fully loaded, savetime, load next test, etc. ?

I know I can use the `Google Chrome console`, `Firebug` or any other plugin, but I do not want to get the speed manually, since I have a lot of pages to compare.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You may be able to write a test using http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html